# Frying chicken wings all the way through

Tags: chicken, deep-frying, chicken-wings

I have tried deep frying chicken wings few times. 
The first time I tried it, the oil was heated a lot and I continued Frying it until it was crisp outside,but when ate it, it was not cooked all the way through, it was pink and the joints of the wings still had blood. 
Second time, because I thought it was because I cooked the wings on high heat, it was burned on the outside but still not cooked inside, I tried Frying the wings in low heat, but the result was the same, undercooked bloody joints in the wings and burned skin. 
So how do I deep fry the chicken wings so that it is cooked all the way through? 
Do I boil it in water before i deep fry?

Comment: You need to supply the temperatures you used and the time you fried the wings in both cases, otherwise there's not enough information to go on.

Comment: I don't have a thermometer to check the temperature accurately but I'd say it was around 100-120 C the first time and around 60-70 the second time. So is it really all about the temperature?

Comment: 60-70C isn't enough to warm your chicken through, much less fry the skin, I would say you are probably very off on these temperatures.

Comment: @GdD Guess I need to buy a thermometer i guess :) I just want to know the techniques that would cook the wings all the way through. Any suggestions would help. Please assume i have a thermometer, I will buy one if needed ;)

Comment: Temperature is very much an essential element of some techniques, especially deep-frying. I second the need for a thermometer. Once you get the temp right, proper deep-frying technique is pretty simple.

Comment: are you sure you know how to recognize undercooked meat? "The joints had blood" - this isn't blood, and this look can be found in well cooked meat too.

Comment: @rumtscho the blood is there plus it tastes like raw meat more or less. I a 100% sure that the meat is undercooked because of the taste, smell, feel and of  course the blood

Comment: I like to pressure cook my chicken wings, then chill.  At that point, the fry step is simply for crisping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your temperature is way too hot. You need a thermometer as there's no reliable way to tell the temperature of your oil without one. A simple method is 190C for 10-15 minutes depending on the size of the wings, that's from refrigerator temperature.

Serious eats has a page on wings [here](http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/01/the-food-lab-how-to-make-best-buffalo-wings-fry-again-ultimate-crispy-deep-fried-buffalo-wings.html) if you want to get more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Properly cooking chicken wings through is the technique many restaurants and bars are made or broken on. Cooking an item that has a lot of skin and bone, and cooking ti correctly, is a challenge.

You mention boiling them first, basically a par cooking step. This is an excellent way to get wings cooked through, with crispy outer texture. It can also be used to impart flavor. I frequently par boil wings in a liquid with aromatics, then cool and carefully dry. This is critical, as you don't want extra water.

Many cooks and restaurants also par-FRY wings. This allows you to cook them through and have them ready to go at a faster rate to serve, and allows for crisp texture. Give that a try !

Answer (score -1):

Don't parboil or boil the chicken wings first!!!  That is a no-no. Simply wash, pat dry, and season to your liking.  Next, make sure the oil in your frying pan (4qt. pot if cooking a bunch)is enough to cover your chicken.  Heat on medium-high heat, covering with a top during the first side of frying.About 5 minutes or so. Once you have a golden coating, turn chicken over, ****leave off the top ***, and continue to cook for approx. 10 to 12 minutes. NOTE: With the top on the first side of cooking, the contained heat will cook the meat to the bone.

Comment: What's the problem with parboiling the chicken first? Also why turn the chicken over if the oil covers all the chicken from the beginning?

Comment: @Luciano - not sure about the first, but for turning over it does often matter as the directional heat (bottom up) can make a difference for browning.